# Prove that every eulerian graph with odd number of vertices contains 3 vertices of the same degree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following problem:

> Prove that every eulerian graph with odd number of vertices
> contains 3 vertices of the same degree.

I know that eulerian graph must have every vertices of even degree, but I am not sure how to continue from that.

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume our graph has at least $3$ vertices. By definition, a graph $G$ is Eulerian if $G$ is connected and every vertex in $G$ has even degree. Now, suppose $|V(G)| = n$ odd. Then, $n-1$ is even so the possible degrees of $G$ are $\{2,4,6,...,n-1\}$ (We do not include $0$ since $G$ is connected). So, there are $\frac{n-1}{2}$ elements in this set. But we have $n$ vertices so by Pigeonhole Principle, at least $3$ of these have the same degree.

Comment: How do we know that there are $\frac{n-1}{2}$ elements in the set?

Comment: Since $n$ is odd, we can say $n = 2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, the set is $\{2,4,6,...,2k\}$ clearly has $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$ elements.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, good luck! :)